# Is there any reason for the order of the attributes "grace, kindness and mercy" in tefillah?

Tags: tefilla

There seems to be a consistency in *tefillah* (prayer) that the attributes חן וחסד ורחמים - (my translation) "grace, kindness and mercy" - appear specifically in this order. Five samples that I can think of:

- First bracha of Benching (Grace after meals)
- Fourth bracha (*Hatov vehameitiv*) in Grace after meals
- Last bracha of *Amidah* (*Sim Shalom*)
- Extra paragraph added for *Kaddish Derabanan* (same words but in Aramaic.)
- In *Yekum Purkan* said on Shabbat (words in Aramaic.)

Is there any reason as to why these attributes are mentioned in this specific order?

I surmised that it may have been imitating the 13 attributes, but, there, mercy רחום precedes kindness חנון.

Comment: could it just be literary/poetic (1 then 2 then 3 syllables)?

Answer (score 5):

The Aruch Hashulchan, when discussing birchat hamazon (ערוך השולחן אורח חיים סימן קפז) writes in se'if 4:

> ולי נראה שנוסחתינו מכוונת יותר דהכוונה של חן חסד רחמים נ"ל **דהנה ג' מדרגות יש בבני אדם** יש עשירים גדולים וזהו בחן על דרך ונח מצא חן כלומר השפעה יתירה ויש בעלי בתים ממוצעים שכל מה שצריכים משיגים בנקל ואין להם מותרות וזהו בחסד שהש"י משפיע לו חסדו שכל מה שצריך משיג בקלות ויש עניים שלחמם בא להם בקושי וזהו ברחמים כי אין שם רחמים נופל אלא במקום שמדת הדין שורה ואח"כ אומרים הוא נותן לחם לכל בשר כלומר הוא נותן לחם לכל אלא שלזה נותן במדה זו ולזה במדה זו כי לעולם חסדו כלומר שאפילו העני לטובתו הוא להרבות שכרו בעוה"ב או לנכות לו מעונותיו או עניין אחר וכמו שאמרו בפסחים [קי"ח.] ע"ש וגם נכלל בנותן לחם לכל בשר כל הברואים לבד האדם ולכן שייך לומר הוא כלומר שזה שמזין האדם מזין לכל ברואי עולם

There seems to be (at least in this case) a sense of scale and rising through the three attributes.

Comment: When possible, translate or summarize. Very interesting explanation. I'm uncertain if it applies to every situation in tefillah and just *Birkat Hamazon*. Offhand, the explanation seems general enough to explain the consistency of the order.